# Dynamic tesselation with displacement map

Tags: displacement

Is there a way to have an object automatically tesselated depending on the detail that is painted in the texture? I want to keep non-detailed parts low poly and detailed parts very highy subdivided. Dynotopo is doing this in sculpting mode.

[image]
(image from creativeshrimp.com)

I stumbled over the technique of vector displacement but this might be too advanced for what I need.